# Bash read line and clone it

Tags: bash, sed, line, clone

Ok, I've many files that have this structure:

```
mail1@mail.it
mail2@mail.com
mail3@mail.co.uk
```

Now I'm trying to convert those files, to have this results

```
mail1@mail.it;mail1@mail.it
mail2@mail.com;mail2@mail.com
mail3@mail.co.uk;mail3@mail.co.uk
```

This because I've to import this file to create a mailing list, so at every line I need to have a return in windows style.

I tried to to this with sed but I don't know, and I don't have found not so much in this days

I tried this approach:

```
sed 's/^/;/' input.txt > output.txt
```

But I miss how to "clone" the content of each line, the idea is pretty simple
I read the line and I paste it with a ; at the end, so the result must be right.

Any ideas how to replicate the content of each line?

J

Comment: Maybe something like `s/^(.*)$/\1;\1/` would do the trick? This uses a capturing group, then simply repeats it twice in the output.

Comment: `join -t ";" --nocheck-order -o 1.1,2.1 file file`

Comment: the best way to preserve the crlf structure is to use python, in my case. Tnx for the reply I've also tried your approach but the results file have the the ; on new line and that is incompatible with my program.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{print $0";"$0}' file
```

Output:

```
mail1@mail.it;mail1@mail.it
mail2@mail.com;mail2@mail.com
mail3@mail.co.uk;mail3@mail.co.uk
```

Comment: tnx, I tried, works on shel but the result file is not crlf, so the program don't recognize it

Comment: @JormanFranzini: use this: `awk '{print $0";"$0"\r"}' file` to get crlf.

Answer (score 1):

Better you use `paste` for this:

```
paste -d';' file file
mail1@mail.it;mail1@mail.it
mail2@mail.com;mail2@mail.com
mail3@mail.co.uk;mail3@mail.co.uk
```

You can use `sed` also (**will work with CRLF line ending also**):

```
sed -i.bak $'s/\([^\r]*\).*/\\1;\\1/' file
mail1@mail.it;mail1@mail.it
mail2@mail.com;mail2@mail.com
mail3@mail.co.uk;mail3@mail.co.uk
```

Comment: tnx, I tried with sed, not with paste, works on shel but the result file is not crlf, so the program don't recognize it

Answer (score 1):

`paste -d';' file file` outputs:

```
mail1@mail.it;mail1@mail.it
mail2@mail.com;mail2@mail.com
mail3@mail.co.uk;mail3@mail.co.uk
```

Answer (score 0):

As shown by others awk,sed or paste are the best ways of doing this, but.. Lets do some more!

bash loop:

```
cat file | while read line ; do echo "$line;$line"; done
```

perl:

```
perl -pe 's/(.*)/$1;$1/' file
```

ruby:

```
ruby -ne 'puts $_.chomp + ";" + $_' < file
```

python:

```
python -c "import sys;[sys.stdout.write(line.rstrip() + ';' + line) for line in sys.stdin]" < file
```

And now I've run out of things

Comment: Tnx, I don't have ruby on my nas, but, the only way, in my case to do this trick is to use python, with this kind of approach I obtain a dos file that preserve the crlf style so I can import it on my program

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
sed 's/.*/&;&/' input.txt > output.txt
```

- `.*` matches the whole line
- `&` is a placeholder for *all the pattern content*

Comment: tnx, I tried, works on shel but the result file is not crlf, so the program don't recognize it.

Comment: pass it to a translator unix->MS world or add `^M` (press CTRL + M together) after last `&` in the line